# Getting error in command line in Tesseract in Windows

Tags: command-line, windows-7, ocr, tesseract, windows-xp-sp3

I am following this documentation-https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3 
I am trying to make a font for my language using this command-

```
training/ text2image --text=training_text.txt --outputbase=bn.Boishakhi.exp1 --font=Boishakhi --fonts_dir=C:\
```

I am getting this error

```
"Training is not recognized as external or internal command", on windows xp sp3 command line.
```

I am also having another problem.I ran tesseract successfully in windows xp sp3(English default traindata) but I cannot run it from command line to generate output in Windows 7 and 8.1. The commands I used are as follows:

```
cd C:\
cd Program Files
cd Tesseract-OCR
tesseract C:\Document.tif output -l eng
```

Please help.

I tried to change /(slash)  to  \ (backslash) but now the new error is "Cannot find the path specified"

As far as running in windows 7 or 8.1 is concerned, the error is "cannot create output file output.txt"

Answer (score 2):

The first message means that the executable `training` was not found on the path. If the required executable was `text2image` then the space should be removed and the correct directory-separator used. `\` separates directories in Windows; `/` introduces switches.

So `training\text2image...` should cure the problem, provided `text2image` is an executable found in `training`  which is a subdirectory of whatever is the current directory, **or** you could use an absolute path, `"C:\wherever\you have installed\tessteract\training\text2image"` - and "note the quotes" that are required if the path to the name includes spaces (optional otherwise.)

As for your second question, you have unaccountably provided no information about any error messages you received, or how the system responded, so any response will be a guess. It may have something to do with the default protected status of the root directory `C:\` and it may not. Please edit the question to include the error message or run report.

Comment: Can you please help now?

Comment: Possibly. I'll just repeat: `It may have something to do with the default protected status of the root directory C:\ and it may not. ` I have no intention of reading the `tesseract` documentation to find out what the switches mean. The report is clearly "cannot create output file output.txt" It's likely that the output file is actually `C:\output.txt` since the input file is `C:\Document.tif` As I've said, the `C:\` directory is likely to be protected, so change the output file specification to output the file to a directory where you have write-access.

Comment: I also had this problem in windows 10 Pro fixed by using latest version of tesseract and also add in proper path